# How is the error of FindGeometricTransform calculated?

Tags: geometric-transform

This question has beeen asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149301/what-does-the-alignment-error-returned-from-findgeometrictransform-measure) but was not answered.

How is the returned error calculated?

I cannot find any information about this in the documentation of `FindGeometricTransform`.

It is only indicated:

> "`FindGeometricTransform` returns an expression of the form `{err,trfun}`,
>   where `err` is an estimate of the average alignment error, and `trfun` is
>   a transformation function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the mean Euclidean distance of the points after transformation.

```
{err, transform} = FindGeometricTransform[data2, data1];
err
```

> 0.315546

```
Mean@MapThread[EuclideanDistance, {transform@data1, data2}]
```

> 0.315546

Comment: This is great. Form where did you find the information?

Comment: I just worked it out. There were only so many ways it could be done, and mean euclidean distance seemed to make the most sense

Comment: I would be happy to get an additional comment regarding `EuclideanDistance` : in my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189124/fitting-of-2d-data-points-with-a-function-considering-scaling-rotation-and-tran is a comment from me below Cesareos answer. **What is your opinion about that**?

Comment: 4000 km??? Incredible.

Comment: I'll answer your `EuclideanDistance` question on that question. Also, thanks a lot, it's really been an amazing project! Do check out https://toughsoles.ie if you're interested :)