# Fitting of 2d data points with a function considering scaling, rotation and translation

Tags: fitting

I have the following set of 2d data points:

```
data1=
{
{21.557, 801.607}, {5.84689, 800.425}, {50.9284, 770.49}, 
{46.4516, 750.192}, {32.9808, 671.931}, {48.8067, 673.198}, 
{3.59394, 671.167}, {18.1513, 671.949}, {64.1628, 670.801}, 
{13.1805, 652.588}, {55.6619, 651.298}, {26.9262, 650.35}, 
{41.4876, 650.752}, {5.45129, 635.602}, {20.3858, 633.391}, 
{64.1931, 632.506}, {33.9168, 631.006}, {58.7559, 613.401}, 
{36.0045, 612.007}, {23.5348, 608.289}, {54.6781, 598.251}, 
{26.4914, 548.723}, {65.0549, 531.442}, {82.9996, 514.631}, 
{74.4132, 479.425}, {58.3295, 458.015}, {27.1816, 413.334}
}
```

I want to apply `ScalingTransform`, `TranslationTransform` and `RotationTransform` to find the best fit to transform `data1` into `data2`, whereby:

```
data2=
{
{1530.03, 790.2}, {1514.13, 789.}, {1559.17, 758.9}, 
{1554.5, 738.5}, {1540.5, 660.237}, {1556.15, 661.154}, 
{1511.34, 659.395}, {1525.63, 660.167}, {1572.13, 658.656}, 
{1520.66, 640.844}, {1562.55, 639.132}, {1533.79, 638.607},     
{1548.37, 638.933}, {1512.62, 623.985}, {1526.88, 621.69},   
{1571.44, 620.556}, {1540.44, 618.794}, {1565.69, 601.532}, 
{1543.06, 600.093}, {1530.22, 596.423}, {1560.9, 586.053}, 
{1532.93, 536.587}, {1571.9, 519.25}, {1590.15, 501.882}, 
{1580.39, 467.111}, {1564.73, 445.615}, {1532.8, 400.935}
}
```

The corresponding points of `data1` that should be transformed into `data2` are already sorted and at the same position of the lists.

Here are plots of the two data sets:

```
plot1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotRange -> {{1, 91}, {300, 900}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "data1"}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large];

plot2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotRange -> {{1510, 1600}, {300, 900}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "data2"}}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large];

GraphicsColumn[{plot1, plot2}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Spacings -> {{0, 0}, {0, 50}}]
```

[image]

I use the following naming:

```
s = ScalingTransform[{sx, sy}, {psx, psy}];
t = TranslationTransform[{vecx, vecy}];
r = RotationTransform[theta, {prx, pry}];
```

The combined transformation for each point `{x, y}` of `data1` is:

```
combinedTransformation = s.t.r;
```

and finally :

```
combinedTransformation[{x, y}] =

{sx (prx (-Cos[theta]) + prx + pry Sin[theta]) + psx (-sx) + psx + 
  sx x Cos[theta] - sx y Sin[theta] + sx vecx, 
 sy (-(prx Sin[theta]) + pry (-Cos[theta]) + pry) + psy (-sy) + psy + 
  sy x Sin[theta] + sy y Cos[theta] + sy vecy}
```

The fitting parameters are: `sx, sy, vecx, vecy, theta`.

The scaling is centered at the point `{psx, psy}` and the 2d rotation  is around the point `{prx, pry}`.

I would set `{psx, psy} = {1, 1}` and `{prx, pry} = {1, 1}`.

**How can I transform `data1` best into `data2` and how can I obtain the fitting paramaters and their errors?**

**ADDENDUM:**

I already tried the same as what is proposed below by Ulrich Neumann and Carl Lange.

- The problem with `FindGeometricTransform` is, it is not described how the error is obtained - I need this for a paper. See this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189107/how-is-the-error-of-findgeometrictransform-calculated).
- Second `FindGeometricTransform` does not give me the rotation angle and scaling factor in x and y separately, which are not exactly the same. 
  `FindGeometricTransform` shows only the transformation function (or matrix) which is not enough for me.

Comment: Try `FindGeometricTransform` . It 's not necessary to require  a `scaling point` and/or  a `rotationpoint` , that is the task ogf the fitting procedure.

Comment: How do you define "the error"?  Is that the mean distance between each point in data2 to the nearest point in the transformed data1?  Or the square root of the mean of the square of those distances?  Or something else?  If the former, then (using @CarlLange 's code) `data1Transformed = transform@data1;
data2Nearest = Flatten[Nearest[data2, #] & /@ data1Transformed, 1];
Mean[Norm[#] & /@ (data1Transformed - data2)]`might do it.

Comment: If by "their errors" you mean the errors in the individual parameters, you'd need to specify a probabilistic model that generates the transformation parameters.  Much like in a linear regression you need not just $y=a+bx$ but $y=a+bx+error$.

Comment: I answered the question about what the error is in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189107/how-is-the-error-of-findgeometrictransform-calculated) of yours.

Comment: Please see this follow up question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189592/removing-anomalous-points-from-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  `FindGeometricTransform`

```
trafo = FindGeometricTransform[data2, data1 ];
F = TransformationMatrix[trafo[[2]]]
```

`F[[{1, 2}, 3]]` is the offset. Matrix

```
T= F[[{1, 2}, {1,2}]]
```

describes rotation and scaling .

```
S = MatrixPower[ Transpose[T].T , 1/2]  (* scaling matrix*)
(*{{0.970832, -0.00629071}, {-0.00629071, 1.00107}}*)
R = Inverse[Transpose[T]].S             (* rotation matrix *)
(*{{0.999918, 0.0128058}, {-0.0128058, 0.999918}}*)
T - R.S // Chop                         (*T==R.S*)
```

The scaling factors are given by the eigenvalues of S.
The rotation angle can be obtained by

```
J = #.# &[Flatten[RotationMatrix[\[CurlyPhi]] - R]];
NMinimize[{J, 0 <= \[CurlyPhi] <= 2 Pi  }, \[CurlyPhi]]
(*{4.36514*10^-15, {\[CurlyPhi] -> 6.27038}}*)
\[CurlyPhi]/Degree /. %[[2]]  (* angle in degree*)
(*359.266*)
```

Comment: Please see the addendum.

Comment: Thank you very much. What is the angle in degree (should be in the order of 0.5 degree)? The scaling factors should be about 1,004 in y and about 1.001 in x (data2 are larger by this factors). 
Do you understand what the error of `FindGeometricTransform` exactly means?

Comment: Angle is around `-.38 Degree`.

Comment: Affine is a linear transformation and translation. I know from measurements that there must also be rotation. Is a rotation included in the affine transformation?  I should add: **the data points are obtained by looking with two cameras on the same objects. `data1` and `data2` are the positions of these objects in the two cameras. In our experiment we know from reference images that the cameras are a little bit tilted against each other**.

Comment: Ok, then it is  the general case  of GeometricTransform! Please correct the title of your question.

Comment: So nearly all your results (with Affine) are now in the order of what also Cesareo obtained. You get: scaling factors=`{1.0044, 1.00225}`; Translation=`{1502.57, -13.1302}`; Angle=`0.36732` degree. Only the y shift is different from Cesareo but fits better to my estimation:`Mean[data2[[All, 2]] - data1[[All, 2]]]=-11.95`. Great ...

Comment: That's because the general mapping used by `GeometericTransform` maps vectors `x->y` in the form `y=(A.x+b)/(c.x+d)` and describes the **central projection** completly. The affine case `c=0,d=1` is only a rough approximation!

Comment: An affine transformation contains also information about shear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation . How can I extract this values?

Comment: @mrz Usually the mean of nondiagonal elements of `S` describe shear: `(S[[1,2]]+S[2,1])/2, (S[[1,3]]+S[3,1])/2,(S[[2,3]]+S[3,2])/2`...

Answer (score 3):

Per Ulrich Neumann's comment, `FindGeometricTransform` will do the job very nicely.

We get the transform by doing

```
transform = FindGeometricTransform[data2, data1][[2]]
```

This gives us a `TransformationFunction`, in this case:

$$
\text{TransformationFunction}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.970671 & 0.00652924 & 1502.57 \\
 -0.0187224 & 1.00107 & -12.4938 \\
 -0.0000212516 & -\text{2.8535460791719293$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7} & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]
$$

Now we can apply that `TransformationFunction` to our data and plot the result:

```
ListPlot[{transform@data1, data2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the addendum.

Comment: Please read also my last comment to Ulrich Neumann.

Answer (score 2):

First change the function combinedTransformation to

```
combinedTransformation[{x_, y_}] = 
{sx (prx (-Cos[theta]) + prx + pry Sin[theta]) + psx (-sx) + psx + 
sx x Cos[theta] - sx y Sin[theta] + sx vecx, 
sy (-(prx Sin[theta]) + pry (-Cos[theta]) + pry) + psy (-sy) + psy + 
sy x Sin[theta] + sy y Cos[theta] + sy vecy}
```

and then try

```
v   = Map[combinedTransformation, data1] - data2;
err = Sum[v[[k]].v[[k]], {k, 1, Length[v]}];
sol = NMinimize[err, {prx, pry, psx, psy, sx, sy, vecx, vecy, x, y, theta}]
```

and the result

[image]

The plot was produced as

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Map[combinedTransformation, data1] /. sol[[2]], 
PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "data1 and data2"}}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large]

plot2 = ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", "data1 and data2"}}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large]

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. You get `sx -> 1.00395, sy -> 1.00219`, which is what I expect. Theta (`theta -> -0.00683116`) is probably in radian which is 0.39 degree, also what I expect. Only the translation surprises me a little bit: `vecx -> 1513.99, vecy -> -7.23374`, compared to the results of Ulrich Neumann and Carl Lange (`vecx ca. 1503 and vecy ca. -13`). I trust their vecy value because of this estimation `vecy = Mean[data2[[All, 2]] - data1[[All, 2]]]=-11.95`. On the other hand: `vecx=Mean[data2[[All, 1]] - data1[[All,1]]]=1507.11` is between your result and their.

Comment: Please read also my last comment to Ulrich Neumann.

Comment: What do you think about the y shift? I have the feeling that it is a little bit underestimated. How did you produce the plot?

Comment: @mrz Included the plotting script

Comment: Thanks for the plot. You used a certain definition for the error which you then put into `NMinimize`. Can you in addition show how the solution would be when the error is calculated with `EuclideanDistance` instead. May be this affects the results for vecx and vecy a little bit . I tried `err = Mean@
   MapThread[
    EuclideanDistance, {Map[combinedTransformation, data1], data2}];` but this seems to be wrong.

Comment: Consider using `FindMinimum` instead of `NMinimize`: `{er, ru} = 
 FindMinimum[
  Mean[MapThread[
    EuclideanDistance, {combinedTransformation /@ data1, 
     data2}]], {prx, pry, psx, psy, sx, sy, vecx, vecy, x, y, theta}, 
  MaxIterations -> 200]` gives roughly the same error as FindGeometricTransform.

Comment: @Carl Lange: I used your code example but get an error message and very strange fitting values, except for the error: https://i.imgur.com/qW9Z9n1.png

Comment: Well, the mean euclidean distance is minimized to the same amount as the `FindGeometricTransform` one. I don't know that the values are strange, I suppose you have better knowledge. You could consider giving the various variables default conditions if you have a decent idea of what the values might be. It's unclear to me that the message is specifically an _error_ message - it looks like it's informational.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to use `NonlinearModelFit` after reorganizing your data:

```
ClearAll[trans, model]
trans[sx_, sy_, tx_, ty_, θ_] := Composition[ScalingTransform[{sx, sy}, {1, 1}], 
  TranslationTransform[{tx, ty}], RotationTransform[θ, {1, 1}]]
model[sx_, sy_, tx_, ty_, θ_][x_] := Module[{h, v}, 
  Flatten@Transpose@CoefficientArrays[trans[sx, sy, tx, ty, θ][{h, v}], {h, v}]. Array[x, 6]]

designmat = ArrayFlatten[{{#, 0}, {0, #}}] &@(Prepend[#, 1] & /@ data1);
response = Join @@ Transpose[data2];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Join[designmat, List /@ response, 2], 
   {model[sx, sy, tx, ty, θ][x], 0 <= θ <= 2 Pi}, {sx, sy, tx, ty, {θ, Pi}}, 
   Array[x, 6]];

Row[{ListPlot[{data2, Transpose[Partition[#, Length[#]/2] &@nlm["PredictedResponse"]]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Medium], Blue], 
     Directive[PointSize[.03], Opacity[.4], Red]}, ImageSize -> 400], 
  MapAt[Style[#, 16] &, nlm["ParameterTable"], {1}]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. Thanky you. Only th angle I do not understand: In the two solutions below both get Ulrich Neumann and Cesareo get an angle of about 0.38 to 0.39 degree.

Comment: @mrz, the estimated angle is `359.607` Degrees (`6.27632/Degree`).

Comment: Great. How do you receive this value from theta?

Comment: @mrz, `theta / Degree` transforms `theta` (in radians) to degrees.

Comment: All values which you receive are similar as of Ulrich Neumann and Cesareo except for the translation. Ulrich Neumann got `{1502.57, -13.1302}` and Cesareo got `{1513.99, -7.23374}`. You got `{1496.06, -13.01}`. My approximate estimation for the `vertical translation is = Mean[data2[[All, 2]] - data1[[All, 2]]]=-11.95` and for the `horizontal translation = Mean[data2[[All, 1]] - data1[[All,1]]]=1507.1`.Which values of the there solutions are most reliable?

Comment: Is in your model also a shear possible?

Comment: @mrz, re "most reliable" maybe you can compare some fit measure,  e.g., `RootMeanSquare` of residuals.

Comment: @mrz, re shear, you can use the estimated transformation, `estimatedtransformation = 
 trans[sx, sy, tx, ty, \[Theta]] /. nlm["BestFitParameters"]`, and follow the suggestion in Ulrich's answer and comment.