# How can I crop an x axis range and combine left and right part of a plot?

Tags: plotting

I remeber that I saw once a similar question, but I can not find it anymore.

I can make a combined plot of the two data set `data1` and `data2`:

```
data1 = Get @ "https://pastebin.com/raw/RDYqjCeA";
data2 = Get @ "https://pastebin.com/raw/e3qcivH0";

ListPlot[{data1, data2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1600}, {300, 900}} , 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Since `data1` and `data2` have a large x distance I would like to crop a part of the x range and produce a similar plot like this one:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: Use `AspectRatio -> 3`

Comment: @Alex Trounev: I don't want to change the aspect ratio. The whole range between 100 and 1500 has to be cropped. Please check the outcome of your proposal.

Comment: Maybe you want to combine two parts of one image?

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Yes, that would be also an idea.

Comment: related q/a: [Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TranslationTransform` on `data2`:

```
ListPlot[{TranslationTransform[{-1300, 0}]@data1, data2, 
  Thread[{{100, 200}, 300}], Thread[{{100, 200}, 900}]},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {300, 900}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Joined -> {False, False, True, True},
 PlotStyle -> Join[Directive /@Thread[{PointSize[Large], {Red, Blue}}], 
     {#, #} &@ Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], White]],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}},
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {#,#}&@(Range[0, 300, 100] /. x : (200 | 300) -> {x, x + 1300})},
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Calibri"},
 Epilog -> {Dotted, Line@Thread[{{100, 200}, #}] & /@ {300, 900}},
 Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can remove `Epilog` and add two more data sets in the first argument of `ListPlot` and modify `PlotStyle`:

```
pr = Round[PlotRange[ListPlot[#, PlotRange->{Automatic, {300, 900}}]], 50]&/@{data2, data1};
difs = -Subtract @@@ pr[[All, 1]];
gap = 50;
gapcoords = Thread[{{#, gap + #} &@pr[[1, 1, 2]], #}] & /@ pr[[1, 2]];
ticks = {## & @@ #, ## & @@ 
  Thread[{{#[[2]] + gap, #[[2]] + gap + difs[[2]]}, pr[[2, 1]]}]} &@pr[[1, 1]];
trans = {-pr[[2, 1, 1]] + gap + pr[[1, 1, 2]], 0};
ListPlot[{TranslationTransform[trans]@data1, 
  data2, ## & @@ gapcoords, ## & @@ gapcoords}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, Total[difs] + gap}, pr[[1, 2]]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Joined -> {False, False, True, True, True, True},
 PlotStyle -> Join[Directive /@ Thread[{PointSize[Large], {Red, Blue}}], 
  {#, #} & @ Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], White], 
  {#, #} & @ Directive[Thin, Dotted, Black]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {ticks, ticks}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15,  FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
 Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative approach using custom [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html):

```
ClearAll[sf, isf]
sf[t1_, t2_, gap_: 50][x_] := Piecewise[{{x, x <= t1}, 
  {t1 + gap/(t2 - t1) (x - t1), t1 <= x <= t2}, {t1 + gap + (x - t2), x >= t2}}]
isf[t1_, t2_, gap_: 50][x_] := InverseFunction[sf[t1, t2, gap]][x]

pr = Round[PlotRange[ListPlot[#, PlotRange->{Automatic, {300, 900}}]], 50]&/@{data2, data1};
ticks = Join @@ pr[[All, 1]];
gapcoords = Thread[{{pr[[1, 1, 2]], pr[[2, 1, 1]]}, #}] & /@ pr[[1, 2]];

Row[With[{g = #}, ListPlot[{data1, data2, ## & @@ gapcoords, ## & @@ gapcoords},
  Joined -> {False, False, True, True, True, True}, 
  PlotStyle -> Join[Directive /@ Thread[{PointSize[Large], {Red, Blue}}], 
    {#, #} & @ Directive[Thick, CapForm["Butt"], White],
    {#, #} & @ Directive[Thin, Dotted, Black]],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {ticks, ticks}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {MinMax@pr[[All, 1]], pr[[1, 2]]}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{sf[pr[[1, 1, 2]], pr[[2, 1, 1]], g][#] &, 
        isf[pr[[1, 1, 2]], pr[[2, 1, 1]], g][#] &}, "Linear"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}]] & /@ {30, 90}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and so compact that I do not understand everything, especially this command: `FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {#,#}&@(Range[0, 300, 100]/. x : (200 | 300) -> {x, x + 1300})}`. Could you show what has to be changed when the dashed line would be between x=100 and x=150? Can the x axis start exactly at 0? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Now I slowly understand how the code works. In my data analysis project I compare your plot with a geometric transformation of the two data sets (you helped me there too: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189124/fitting-of-2d-data-points-with-a-function-considering-scaling-rotation-and-tran). There data points partly overlap and instead of using points I defined markers to distinguish them better: `symbolPlusBlue = 
  Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}}}]}];`and `symbolCrossRed = 
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}}]}];`.

Comment: @mrz, try  `PlotMarkers -> {{symbolCrossRed, 0.1}, {symbolPlusBlue, 0.1}, "", "", 
  "", ""}`.

Comment: But it has to somehow to replace `Thread[{PointSize[Large] ...`?

Comment: @mrz, the size specified in plot markers overrides the `PointSize` directive in `PlotStyle`; so you can leave `PlotStyle` as is or use `{Red, Blue}` instead of `Directive /@ Thread[{PointSize[.3], {Red, Blue}}`.